# Is there a way to set an imported library so that it ignores my custom CSS?

Tags: css, reactjs

In my react project, I styled the buttons like this in an external stylesheet file called project.css:

```css
 button {
        max-width: 150px;
        margin: 20px 0;
        padding: 12px 20px;
        border-style: none;
        border-radius: 5px;
        color: #fff;
        cursor: pointer;
        outline: none;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
    }
```

This has been working fine, however I recently installed some libraries that also use buttons.  My button style that you see above, is interfering with the style the libraries use.

I was wondering how I could keep my button styles, but have the libraries I use ignore my custom button styles.

Is this doable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the structure of your code and the libraries code there are a few options.

1. Load the library styles after your own. When two selectors have the same specificity the last one loaded applies.
2. Scope your selector under a parent selector unique to your application

   .mycode button {
   ...
   }
3. Migrate your selector to a class instead of targetting the button tag.

   .mybutton {
   ...
   }

In general its more flexible to target a custom css class than the tags themselves.